# Types of noises when predicting a time series like electricity loads and exchange prices

Tags: time-series, prediction, forecasting, noise, forecast

In another question I presented my developed methodology to add noise to a time series of electricity loads and exchange prices. With these noisy time series I want to test how well my system can cope with predicted time series ([Function for testing system stability, which receives predicted time series as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56239172/function-for-testing-system-stability-which-receives-predicted-time-series-as-i)).

[RobertBaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3826387/robertbaron) pointed out that my methodology only adds "white noise" (i.e. normally distributed noise) to a time series.

Hence the question:
What other types of noise are typically added when predicting electricity loads and exchange prices?